# Equation of circle with given radius passing through two given points

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Find the equation of the circles passing through two points on the $y$ axis at distances 3 units from the origin and having radius 5.

(This a homework problem but I do not know how to solve it.)

Comment: OK, but what do you know? What do you know about the equation of a circle? what if the circle has radius 5? What are the two points on the $y$-axis at distance 3 from the origin?

Comment: I know the equation of the circle, etc, but I dont understand this question properly.

Comment: OK, so, what is the equation of a circle with radius 5? What are the points on the $y$-axis, 3 units from the origin?

Comment: The equation of circle with radius  is $x^2+y^2=25$ and point on y axis is $(0,3)$

Comment: That's one circle with radius 5, the one centered at the origin. What if the center is somewhere else? Also, that's one of the points 3 units from the origin, but there's another one, isn't there?

Comment: Yes, the other point is $(0,-3)$.

Comment: Good. And what about the circles I asked about?

Comment: Thank you I understood it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the circle which intersects the points $(0, 3)$ and $(0, -3)$, whose radius is $5$. To find the center of the circle, you need to find the point $(x_0, y_0)$ such that $$\sqrt{(x_0 - 0)^2 + (y_0 - 3)^2} = \sqrt{(x_0 - 0)^2 + (y_0 + 3)^2} = 5$$

Note that this center must necessarily be located on the $x$-axis: $(x_0, y_0) = (x_0, 0)$, determined by $x_0, -x_0$, each of which will define a distinct circle.

The general equation of a circle with center $(x_0, y_0)$ and radius $r$ is given by:

$$(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 = r^2$$

Comment: I still cannot understand this. Can you please provide more explanantion?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I now understood this.

Comment: You're welcome, Vibha!

Comment: @GerryMyerson I appreciate your efforts in comments, and your patience. In this case, though, perhaps you underestimated the OP's knowledge. It's hard to call such situations.

Comment: @amWhy: That is such nice feedback +1